# IBM Connections createGCD

Tags: websphere, connection

I am setting up the IBM Connections 5.5 and am stuck while creating GCD. Please find the errors below. Any help in this would be helpful.

```
2016-11-19 03:59:24 *** Creating Domain and GCD ...
2016-11-19 03:59:27 com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException: FNRCA0031E: API_UNABLE_TO_USE_CONNECTION: The URI for server communication cannot be determined from the connection object http://IMPERIUM04.ibmsw.ibm.aessatl.arrow.com:9082/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM. Message was: Connection refused: connect
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst.cOpenMultipartOutputStream(ServiceSessionNst.java:287)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst.cReqRespPath(ServiceSessionNst.java:170)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst.executeChanges(ServiceSessionNst.java:85)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.util.SessionHandle.executeChanges(SessionHandle.java:112)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.callExecuteChanges(Session.java:146)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.executeChanges(Session.java:532)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.executeChange(Session.java:850)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.IndependentlyPersistableObjectImpl.save(IndependentlyPersistableObjectImpl.java:76)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.IndependentlyPersistableObjectImpl.save(IndependentlyPersistableObjectImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.connections.ccmDomainTool.ccmDomainTool.createP8Domain(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.connections.ccmDomainTool.ccmDomainTool.main(Unknown Source)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:97)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:370)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:231)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:404)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:643)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:188)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:462)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:557)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:226)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:329)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:347)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1010)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:946)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:864)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst$1.run(ServiceSessionNst.java:391)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:420)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst.cDoPrivilegedHttpConnectAndGetOutputStream(ServiceSessionNst.java:400)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst.cInitHttpConnection(ServiceSessionNst.java:361)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst.cOpenMultipartOutputStream(ServiceSessionNst.java:279)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The relevant error here is `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`. From the given URL, the application is trying to connect to 'IMPERIUM04.ibmsw.ibm.aessatl.arrow.com:9082'.

Verify that the hostname and port name are correct. If the details are correct, ensure that the address is reachable. If you are on an enterprise environment, make sure that the firewall is configured to allow this connection.

Comment: I think that the hostname and port numbers are correct as I am able to enter into the link "http://imperium04.ibmsw.ibm.aessatl.arrow.com:9082/acce". Also, I have added all the port numbers between 9080 to 9082 in the inbound rule of windows server to allow the port numbers in the windows firewall.

Comment: Three things to try: 1) Use telnet from the source server to check if the connection actually goes through to the target server: `telnet imperium04.ibmsw.ibm.aessatl.arrow.com 9082`. 2) Server hostnames are supposed to be case insensitive, but some applications work differently. Correct the hostname accordingly and try again. 3) See if the target server has a whitelisting-type policy for its firewall. You may have to add an exception for your connection to be accepted.